# JqueryMobile loading icon inconsistent

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm dealing with some inconsistencies on the loading message of jquerymobile. It seems that there is no rhyme or reason as to when the icon shows up. Sometimes it shows up right when I hit a button, other times it takes a second and then sometimes it doesn't show at all. This is a big usability problem as it appears that my application isn't doing anything and causes the user to tap again. I'd love for the loading button to show up all of the time, no matter the wait. Is there a way to ensure this? I've tried adding an onclick to each of my links with the  following:

```
onclick="$.mobile.loading( 'show' );"
```

but that doesn't seem to do anything. Any help provided would be most appreciated, thanks!

As a side note, I've found JqueryMobile incredibly buggy and hard to work with. It's a promising platform but it is filled with issues.

Comment: are you sure it's jquery mobile, and not phonegap that's the issue?

Comment: That is a good point, however I'm seeing other people not using PG and having some of the same issues. However, PG has it's fair share of issues as well. It seems it's the perfect storm between the two.

Comment: are you using the most recent versions of jquery and jquery mobile?  I had to add showing the loading icon for some content i was getting ajaxly.   the script to show it is: `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();` and to hide it is `$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();`

Comment: Awesome, that worked really well. Much more consistant, Thanks!

Comment: cool, i put that as an answer, so you can mark that as the answer, so this question doesn't show up as not answered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you were using the wrong code to show the icon, this changed a couple versions ago in thinkL

the script to show it is:

```
 $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
```

and to hide it is

```
$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
```